# Serve media files with Debug=False

Tags: wagtail

Using wagtail 2.4 and django 2.2 I can't seem to get media files to serve up and in the admin, all the uploaded images disappear.

I have this in my settings.py

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

If I set Debug = True, then the images appear just fine. What setting do I need to set to get my uploaded images to appear in production?

Comment: In my case, my static files are working fine in Production. I'm having trouble with uploaded media files. Those are files that the end user would upload and would be part of the page model.

Comment: I didn't realize MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT work the same way as static.